# Input order in a Redux mapDispatchToProps declaration

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

The thing I can't understand is that in this currying style declaration why is the dispatch input the second one?

Doesn't *connect* call this function with dispatch as input and then assign the return value to props? so the return value should be the function that gets an id as input and does something.

But with my understanding of currying, this function should first be called with an id as input and then the returned function can be called with dispatch input.

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = id => dispatch => {
    //e.g. dispatch an action that deletes that id
};
```

So why is this function correct?

Comment: What exactly does `mapDispatchToProps` do here? Can you please provide some more code for a better context of what the id and dispatch is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do

```
connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Component1)
```

it will not work.

As of [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops),

> The mapDispatchToProps parameter can be of two forms. While the function form allows more customization, the object form is easy to use.
>
> - Function form: Allows more customization, gains access to dispatch and optionally ownProps
> - Object shorthand form: More declarative and easier to use

The function form should return object, but your `mapDispatchToProps` returns a function, so it will be ignored.

I think you see this function as action creator when Redux is used with Redux-thunk. This way it will work, but it should be passed as object prop like this `connect(null, { mapDispatchToProps })(Component1)`. This way it will be available to `Component1`.

Internally, `connect` do the following

1. If you passed function as `mapDispatchToProps` it will be called with `dispatch` as first argument. And `connect` expects object as result that will be merged to props.

   `mapDispatchToProps` can be implemented as below

   ```
    mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        changeID (id) {
            return dispatch => /* some code */
        }
    })
   ```

   Component will receive `changeID` function as prop. And this function can be used only with Redux-thunk. When component calls `changeID` Redux will pass it to Redux-thunk, which in turn call internal function with `dispatch` provided as first argument.
2. If you pass object as `mapDispatchToProps` all props of this object will become part of component props

   ```
   mapDispatchToProps = {
       changeID (id) {
           return dispatch => /* some code */
       }
   }
   ```

   Essentially it ill work the same as code from point 1.

So the main idea is that any function with signature

```
const SomeFunc = id => dispatch => { /* code */ }
```

can only be used with Redux-thunk. Redux-thunk will call internal function providing `dispatch` as first argument.

Without Redux-thunk only following action creators are allowed

```
const SomeFunc = id => ({ type: 'ACTION', id })
```

which are simply action creators.